# Motion detection program for snapping of images

Tags: python, python-3.x, image, opencv, raspberry-pi

I'm doing a motion detection program where it snaps an image when it detects movement and snaps an image of the person's face if in view while this is all recorded and sends it all to Dropbox.

It's moving very slowly and lagging like crazy, showing 1 frame in like a minute. Is there a way to optimize it?

I'm using a Raspberry Pi to code all this, and a webcam.

```
import sys
sys.path.append('/usr/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages')
import numpy as np
import cv2
import imutils
from imutils import contours
import datetime
import time
import dropbox


#Function fo Drawing rect and changing text to REC
def draw_rect_movement(c):
    #Draw Rectangle around found contour object
    (x, y, w, h) = cv2.boundingRect(c)
    cv2.rectangle(frame, (x,y), (x+w,y+h), (0,255,0), 2)
    text = "REC"
    return c    

def saveNupload(roi_color):
    #writing image of face as png in the file
    timestring = time.strftime("%Y_%m_%d_%H_%M_%S")
    face_timestr = 'face_' + timestring + '.png'
    cv2.imwrite(face_timestr, roi_color)

    #Opening for [r]eading as [b]inary
    FaceFile = open(face_timestr, mode = "rb")
    #Reads the number of bytes of the video
    data = FaceFile.read()

    #Setting the save location with file name
    SavetoLocation = '/FYP_Face_Save/'+ face_timestr
    SaveToLocation = str(SavetoLocation)

    dbx.files_upload(data, SaveToLocation)
    #Close for reading and binary
    FaceFile.close()    

dbx = dropbox.Dropbox('Access Token')
dbx.users_get_current_account()

#cap = cv2.VideoCapture("/home/pi/Desktop/Proj/VideoTestSample.mp4")
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(1)

#Creating froeground and removing Background
fgbg = cv2.createBackgroundSubtractorMOG2(detectShadows=False)

#Set format
fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'XVID')
#Get Datetime
timestr = time.strftime("%Y_%m_%d_%H_%M_%S")
#Creating name of folder
timestr = timestr + '.avi'
#Setting Name, Format, FPS, FrameSize
out = cv2.VideoWriter(timestr,fourcc, 10.0, (640, 480))

#setting casacade for use
face_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier('haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml')

#setting criteria for  termination
term_crit = ( cv2.TERM_CRITERIA_EPS | cv2.TERM_CRITERIA_COUNT, 10, 1 )
#As long as the VideoCapture is open loop to show the frames
while (cap.isOpened()):
    #capture frame-by-frame
    (grabbed, frame) = cap.read()
    text = " "

    if not grabbed:
        break

    #Convert frame to Black white and gray
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

    #placing Cascade detection
    faces = face_cascade.detectMultiScale(gray, 1.2,)

    #Drawing around the detected "face"
    for (x, y, w, h) in faces:
        cv2.rectangle(frame, (x -20,y-20), (x + w + 20, y + h + 20), (255,0,0), 2)
        roi_color = frame[y-20:y + h + 20, x -20:x + w + 20]

        saveNupload(roi_color = roi_color)

    #Apply the Background SubtractionMOG2
    fgmask = fgbg.apply(gray)
    #Erode away the boundaries of the foreground object
    thresh = cv2.erode(fgmask, None, iterations=2)

    #Set detect as none
    detect = None

    #FindContours returns a list of the outlines of the white shapes in the mask (and a heirarchy that we shall ignore)   
    (_,cnts,hierarchy) = cv2.findContours(thresh.copy(), cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

    #Draw the DateTime on the bottom left hand corner
    cv2.putText(frame, datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%A %d %B %Y %I:%M:%S%p"),
                (10, frame.shape[0] - 10), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.35,(0,0,255), 1)    

    #detect is object found or not found
    detect = (_,cnts,hierarchy)

    #if object found is detected run these codes
    if detect == (_,cnts,hierarchy):

        #if area of object is lower than 300 ignore it 
        for (i,c) in enumerate(cnts):
            if cv2.contourArea(c) < 1100:
                print("ignore small contours", cv2.contourArea(c))
                continue

            #Uncomment this function call to display motion detected
            ###draw_rect_movement(c = c)

            #Temporary code
            text = "Movement Detected ... Snapping"

            #Capture image
            timestring = time.strftime("%Y_%m_%d_%H_%M_%S")
            image_timestr = 'image_' + timestring + '.png'
            cv2.imwrite(image_timestr, frame)

            #Opening for [r]eading as [b]inary
            ImageFile = open(image_timestr, mode = "rb")
            #Reads the number of bytes of the video
            data = ImageFile.read()

            #Setting the save location with file name
            SavetoLocation = '/FYP_Image_Save/'+ image_timestr
            SaveToLocation = str(SavetoLocation)

            dbx.files_upload(data, SaveToLocation)
            #Close for reading and binary
            ImageFile.close()            

            detect= None 

            if detect != (_,cnts,hierarchy):
                continue

    elif  detect != (_,cnts,hierarchy):
        print("Not Snaping")

    else:
        continue

    #Draw the text at top right hand corner
    cv2.putText(frame, "{}". format(text), (10,20),
                cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.5, (0, 0, 255), 2)

    #Write which window into video in this case Frame
    out.write(frame) 
    #Display the following windows
    cv2.imshow('frame',frame)
    cv2.imshow('gray', gray)
    cv2.imshow('fgmask', fgmask)

    #if q is pressed break loop
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break

#Stop recording 
out.release()
#Kill all windows
cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()

#Opening for [r]eading as [b]inary
VideoFile = open(timestr, mode = "rb")
#Reads the number of bytes of the video
data = VideoFile.read()

#Setting the save location with file name
SavetoLocation = '/FYP_Video_Save/'+timestr
SaveToLocation = str(SavetoLocation)

#Upload the file
print("Sending to Dropbox")
dbx.files_upload(data, SaveToLocation)
#Close for reading and binary
VideoFile.close()
```

Comment: how often is it detecting movement? Make it less often. What is the criteria for "movement" being made? make it looser. How much data is saved in the picture? reduce the size of the picture. secondly why are you converting each picture? that takes a lot of computational power. why not just stick with the original colour? just some suggestions to get you started.

Comment: @BKSpurgeon The "movement" detection is non-stop, i have already limited the amount of movement by alot so only if a person were to enter the frame or the door opening (The camera is only 1-1.5 meters away from the door) it will start to activate the snapping. I dont understand what you mean by **What is the criteria for "movement" being made? make it looser.**  I am converting the pictures to read binary because if i don't it will not be able to upload the pictures to dropbox

Comment: @MarcianNg what i mean is: if one pixel changes will that register a movement? or if many pixels change will that register a movement? unfortunately, i couldn't understand your code: when and what are you uploading to drop box?

Comment: @BKSpurgeon It has to be a group of pixels together for it to detect as movement i have already limited it to an area of 1100  for it to recognize as a movement. It is **immediately** saved as a png file then converted to binary and is uploaded to dropbox. **Same** goes for the face as well. But the video is uploaded at the very end **AFTER** the program is breaked.

Comment: ok. i wish i could help more but i couldn't make out much from the code. anyways, good luck.

Comment: Note about the logic, you are checking for faces first, but if the room is empty, there will no be faces there. So check for movement first, if there is movement, search for face. Detecting movement with contours can be cpu consuming task if there was much contours. try with another approach and see what suits you. I always go wit histograms, like in my question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40514508/opencv-detect-movement-in-python
If there is change in histogram value, I will consider it as change, and its less cpu consuming than contours.

Answer (score 2):

```
sys.path.append('/usr/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages')
```

Recommend you use a proper package manager to install `numpy` and friends,
such as [`conda`](https://docs.conda.io/en/latest/miniconda.html), or `pip` virtualenv.

```
(x, y, w, h) = cv2.boundingRect(c)
```

No need for `(` extra parens `)` on the tuple unpack.
Recommend you run [`$ flake8`](http://flake8.pycqa.org/en/latest/), and heed its advice,
preferring identifiers like e.g. `save_and_upload` or `face_file`.

```
SaveToLocation = str(SavetoLocation)
```

You already had a `str`, so the function call does nothing.

```
#Creating froeground
```

Typo.

```
while (cap.isOpened()):
```

No need for `(` extra parens `)`.
Same remark for the `grabbed, frame` tuple unpack.

```
            detect= None 
            if detect != (_,cnts,hierarchy):
                continue
```

An unconditional `continue` would suffice.

The `while` loop in `__main__` is far too long, and should be packaged up
in one or more helper functions.

You didn't post any profiling / timing data, but
I assume you spend the bulk of elapsed time here:

```
    faces = face_cascade.detectMultiScale(gray, 1.2)
```

Following the advice of BKSpurgeon and Aleksandar,
it would make sense to guard this with some cheap check for changed pixels,
perhaps using `cv2.absdiff()`,
before requesting the full-blown face finder.
Histograms certainly are a good way of summarizing images and noticing gross differences.